# Tkinter with Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am quite new to Python and started learning Tkinter yesterday. I am creating a banking system and I have a Menu made out of the buttons. The problem that I have is that I do not know how to open an additional window when the button is clicked. I have tried with `top=Toplevel()`, but it only opens two windows on top of each other. What I need is for the additional window to open only when it is activated with a button(event). Can someone help me because I am really stuck as I have about six buttons?

My code so far is:

```
root.minsize(width=400, height=400)
root.maxsize(width=400, height=400)
root.configure(background='#666666')
label = Frame(root).pack()
Lb = Label(label, text='Welcome to Main Menu',bg='#e6e6e6', width=400).pack()

menu = Frame(root,).pack()
btn_1 = Button(menu, text='Make Deposit', width=15, height=2).pack(pady=5)
btn_2 = Button(menu, text='Withdrawal', width=15, height=2).pack(pady=5)
btn_3 = Button(menu, text='Accounts', width=15, height=2).pack(pady=5)
btn_4 = Button(menu, text='Balance', width=15 ,height=2).pack(pady=5)
btn_5 = Button(menu, text='Exit', width=15, height=2).pack(pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: You need to pass a function that opens the Toplevel to the `command` option of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work:

```
from Tkinter import *

class firstwindow:
    def __init__(self):
        #Variables
        self.root= Tk()
        self.switchbool=False
        #Widgets
        self.b = Button(self.root,text="goto second window",command= self.switch)
        self.b.grid()
        self.b2 = Button(self.root,text="close",command= self.root.quit)
        self.b2.grid()
        self.root.mainloop()

    #Function to chage window
    def switch(self): 
        self.switchbool=True
        self.root.quit()
        self.root.destroy()

class secondwindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root= Tk()
        self.b2 = Button(self.root,text="close",command= self.root.quit)
        self.b2.grid()
        self.root.mainloop()

one = firstwindow()

if one.switchbool:
    two = secondwindow()
```

Take a look to the [Tkinter reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/tkinter.pdf). Check all universal methods and widgets methods. You can do anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a small example of how you can open a window by clicking on a button. When the user clicks on the button, the function `open_window`, which was passed to the `command` option of the button, is called.

```
import tkinter as tk

def open_window():
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    tk.Button(top, text='Quit', command=top.destroy).pack(side='bottom')
    top.geometry('200x200')

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(root, text='Open', command=open_window).pack()
tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.destroy).pack()

root.mainloop()
```